# Simulate no internet on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to simulate no internet on the emulator apart from disconnecting my computer, I still want to be connected via browser etc.

Setting the signal strength to none doesn't seem to stop apps from getting an internet connection.

Comment: Airplane mode, maybe?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try airplane mode by tapping the relevant icon in the notification tray:

[image: Airplane Mode Setting]

You might also try hitting F8 to "Toggle Cell Network" in the emulator although you may need to manually reconnect ADB after this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, airplane mode is an obvious answer.  Another good way is to run it through a proxy such as fiddler, which would allow you not just to turn off the connection but to fake a bad connection with high packet loss or latency and see how you work.